# How many troops of a given type correspond to a given BR in a Heroic Foray?

Tags: adventurer-conqueror-king

I was going through Autarch's [Domains at War, Starter edition](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/113499/ACKS-Domains-at-War-Free-Starter-Edition?term=domains+at+war) which came with my copy of the ACK system, and in the section on *Heroic Forays* (page 10) it says (emphasis mine):

> A heroic foray is a fight between participating heroes and a
> **selection of foes drawn from the opposing army.** All heroes
> fight in the same foray. **To foray, a hero stakes between 0 and 3
> points of battle rating.** (...) The total amount of
> BR staked by all the heroes will determine how many foes the
> heroes face.
>
> The Judge should select foes for the fray from among the units
> and heroes of the opposing army. (...) If desired, the Judge may have
> **the heroes face partial units, reducing both BR and number of
> creatures proportionately.**

The initial reading is that the heroes (that is, the PCs and possibly their henchmen) will face 0–3 BR worth of foes, depending on how much they are willing to risk their own side's Battle Rating. How much is a BR's worth of foes, though? In page 9, under the heading *Battle Ratings,* we have:

> ... The battle rating of various units is listed in the Battle Rating table. Note that the battle ratings are for regular-sized units of 120 infantry or 60 cavalry or ogres.

and at the foot of the page, we have a *Battle Rating* table which, among other things, establishes that a unit of Mannish light infantry has BR 1 and, if they are heavy infantry instead, BR 2.

That doesn't make a lot of sense, though. Surely, if a player chooses to wager 1 BR in the foray (assuming the other players wager 0), the party will not have to face 120 light infantrymen or 60 heavy infantrymen in combat by themselves? Even if they were strong enough to handle them, these are still numbers far beyond what is generally recommended as numbers for a combat encounter, even if the Judge deploys them in 3–4 waves: the logistics of keeping track of HP and initiative would be sheer chaos. Is this actually the point of the heroic foray, or am I missing something?